# Block certain countries X-forwarded-for - Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-api-gateway, nginx-location, api-gateway

I have a requirement to block certain countries coming to our website.  I managed to achieved it using the ngx_http_geoip_module. I have a problem now, if the request comes through Amazon API Gateway, how can I read the X-forwarded-for header or block these request too.

nginx.conf

```
 map $geoip_country_code $allow_country {
 default yes; 
 US no; 
 }


geoip_country /etc/nginx/GeoIP.dat; # the country IP database 
geoip_city /etc/nginx/GeoLiteCity.dat; # the city IP database
```

domain.conf

```
if ($allow_country = no) { 
return 444; 
}
```

Comment: Have you captured and observed the incoming request headers from API requests?  What did you find, there?  Depending on whether the API is Edge-Optimized and whether it's a proxy integration, you should find or be able to map/remap both `X-Forwarded-For` and `CloudFront-Viewer-Country`, and you should have access to `$context.identity.sourceIp` in the integration request.  There are multiple solutions.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot We have `X-Forwarded-For` header in Integration request and the IP address is logged in our Nginx log. Is it possible for us to block X-Forwarded-For ipranges in geo ip module by Country code.

Comment: How can I get the client IP address if the request is coming through load balancer or Proxy and pass it to geoip module to block it based on the Country.